# Crusader Kings 2+ (Mod) download

Tags: crusader-kings-2

Where can I download the english CK2+ mod? The mod section of the paradox forums appears to be empty, even when logged in. When I google CK2+, I can only find the mod in Russian. However, it seems to be rather popular and clearly exists in english. I honestly cannot find it, probably because "CK2+" has chemistry related search results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should [register your game with Paradox](http://forum.paradoxplaza.com/forum/mygames.php) to see certain forums, like the User Modification forum for Crusader Kings 2. It's their way to provide a little extra to people who don't pirate their games.

Anyway, after you've registered you'll be able to access the [Master Mod List](http://forum.paradoxplaza.com/forum/showthread.php?587747-Crusader-Kings-II-Master-Mod-List) topic which lists and links to about all of the mods for the game, including CK2Plus.